# In Android Can intents and broadcasts pass between user profiles

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, user-profile

There seems to be limited [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html) on this.

Im wondering if I have the same app installed in two different user profiles, and I fire an intent or broadcast applicable for that app, in one user profile, can the same app in the other user profile pick the broadcast or intent?

If so is this true for any android supported IPC such as binding etc...

Can anyone point me to good documentation on this?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but I would think you could do it via google cloud messaging as long as you have an internet connection

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html) you linked provides the information you need, implicitly though.

> *App.* An application’s data exists within each associated user. App data is sandboxed from other applications within the same user. **Apps within the same user** can interact with each other via IPC. For details, refer to [Building Apps for Work](https://developer.android.com/work/index.html).

So you can't communicate with any app of another user.